# Request for Support with CapsLock Key Code

Tags: autohotkey

Request for Support: I modified the following AutoHotkey script previously on a Win7 Pro 64-bit system. The CapsLock key is disabled in the "On" position using this script (which is desirable), then returned to normal on-off toggle state if held for a few seconds.

I have a new Win10 64-bit system and the code no longer works. I would appreciate any suggestions and advice regarding the script below.

```
CapsLock::
    KeyWait, CapsLock
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    If (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 5) and !(state = "D")
        SetCapsLockState, Off
    Else
        SetCapsLockState, on
Return
```

The error codes returned indicated that only spaces and parenthesis are appropriate and that `,`s are reserved for parameters.  However, if I remove the `,`s, other errors popup.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get the same error as you; in fact, no error came up at all. (I suspect the error is from some other portion of code not shown.) However, it also didn't operate for me as you described. I had to increase `A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 5` to `A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 5000` (5 seconds instead of 5 milliseconds) and change `!(state = "D")` to `(state = "D")` (looking for "on" state instead of not "on" ("off")) to make it work to how I think you're describing. My understanding is that it will lock "on" if pressed, but won't turn "off" unless pressed for a period of time (5 sec. in this case); is this correct?

Note that the `GetKeyState` command is deprecated. You may want to use the `GetKeyState()` function instead for future support. Using the function also allows you to use it in expressions, so you don't need to assign it to a variable. Anyway, this was my final code. I used the ternary operator to reduce the if-statement to one line, but this isn't necessary and will work if setup how you have it.

```
CapsLock::
KeyWait , CapsLock
SetCapsLockState , % ( A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 5000 ) && !GetKeyState( CapsLock , T ) ? 0 : 1
Return
```

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your suggestion.  I was unable to load a screen shot of the error but this is the return:
----

AutoHotkeyU64.ahk

Error at line 3.
Line Text: % (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey > = 5000) && !GetKeyState(CapsLock, T) ? 0: 1)
Error: Missing ending "%"

The program will exit.
-----

Suggestions? Ernie

Comment: @ErnieMarshburn What version of AHK are you using?

Comment: The "T" in getKeyState needs to be enclosed in quotes, as it is a literal string argument. Also I think you need to remove the comma after "SetCapsLockState" for forcing an expression in this case.